# java beans interfere one another

Tags: java, jsf, web, javabeans

I have a bean class which renders some chart, it works perfect, but if i make 2 request for the same bean simultaneously, the private properties of bean class are being overridden by second one, resulting in i normal behavior.

```
public class SomeGraphBean extends BaseChartGraphBean{

private String name;

    public ComplianceGraphBean(){
        super();
        name = request.getparameter("name");
    }
......
}
```

So the name is being rendered with the same value for 1-st and 2-nd call if i call simultaneously.

Comment: Can you describe your calling method?

Comment: Not enough information to help, but obviously you either (a) need a new instance, or (b) need the bean to be thread-safe (which might be as simple as using a ThreadLocal).

Comment: Thanks for response:
It is called via action, by struts and rendered with jsp and faces config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">
    <jvcf:chartView
       **id="${id}"**
       height="#{chartHeight}"
       width="#{chartWidth}"
       ...../>
</h:panelGrid>
```

a unique id should be generated for each View

Answer (score 1):

Put the bean in the request or view scope, not in the session or application scope.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)